# How do i write Erobee in Chinesse?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, meaning-in-context, word, writing

I want to use Chinese writing of [Erobee](https://www.erobee.com/) in my logo. Does someone tell me please?

Answer (score 1):

> [Ero](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ero)
>
> A derivation of "erotic"

Bee = 蜜蜂

Erobee obviously means "erotic bee"

The character 春 in Chinese is often associated with 'erotic'

春畫/春宮畫 = erotic painting

春藥 = aphrodisiac

春霄 = night of passionate, tender love

'**春蜂**'would be a good translation for the 'Erobee' brand

> Another Character associate with 'erotic' is '艷'(beautiful) as in '冶艷' (sexy) or '妖艷'(**flirtatious**)
>
> '艷蜂' would be a better name  for a commercial product

Comment: Yes, ero is shot erotic. So is that ok 春蜂

Comment: @Neo Sannyas  See my edition, 艷蜂 (flirtatious bee) would be a better commercial product name

Comment: Thank you so much.  艷蜂 (flirtatious bee) is more enable.

Comment: Hi Dear Tang Ho, 
Would you help me please about an issue please? There is a company from China that it sends hundreds of spam e-mails to my company everyday. I couldn't find where i can complain them. Would you tell me where can i complain please? If you know.
Thanks

Comment: Just put the sender's email address  in spam blocker

Comment: But those are thousands different addresses